# Duplicate a component and make it have its own usestate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with react.
I specify that I am new on react.

In the application I have to design, the user has the possibility to add tables like excel. The table is a react plugin that I downloaded and has its own logic for modifying and managing its useState.

I would like to duplicate the table component inside a loop and have each of them have their own state to modify.
But I don't know how to do this and it seems that this is not recommended by react itself.

Thank you for reading me

Comment: Don't create tables in a loop. Have two table components and just feed them the data they need from the parent component. Welcome to SO, btw. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.